# How to open same modal with multiple button which have same id?

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog

I have a foreach loope where i create x amount of buttons:

```
 <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#unlockModal" id="openUnlockModal" data-uid="@user.Uid" class="btn btn-default btn-sm">test</a>
```

As you can see id is the same for all of those buttons, and ofcourse if i click on one of them only the first one in the list of those buttons will open the modal.

```
 $("#openUnlockModal").on("click", function (event) {
        var uid = $(this).data("uid");
        console.log(uid)
     //open my fancyModal here
    });
```

The problem i am facing that i want to send an id to the modal which is stored on the button which is actually opening it.

So how do i send this id from the button to the modal? and how do i get all buttons to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`id` must be only one for page, you can add event to `class`, like this

```
$(".btn").on("click", function (event) {
    var uid = $(this).data("uid");
    // $(this) will be refer to button which was clicked 
    console.log(uid)
});
```